# Rendering XBRL as hierarchy

Tags: xbrl

I would like to get a structured balance sheet from a 10-Q report with XBRL. There are tons of elements and I would like to dynamically construct the hierarchy (eg. Assets contain Current and Non-current Assets, etc.).

As I understand, for such purpose there are arc elements similar to https://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2020/dei-pre-2020-01-31.xml

Is there any similar one for financial statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the report specific presentation linkbase (which often contains a `pre` in the name; this is not a global rule though, but applies to the SEC filings). The presentation linkbase is linked to the original report through imports.

Here is an example for [apple's recent 10-Q](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0000320193/000032019321000056/aapl-20210327_pre.xml). The hierarchy (balance sheet) you are looking for is in extended link with `xlink:role="http://www.apple.com/role/CONDENSEDCONSOLIDATEDBALANCESHEETSUnaudited"`.